# basic concept for sending receiving sms from C# application using gsm modem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sms, at-command

Can anyone explain me the basic concept or provide me any documentation on sending receiving the sms using the gsm modem connected to pc via a C# application.

I did find lot of source codes but not able to get what is the procedure or algorithm behind it.

One such link is here

http://www.freestudentprojects.com/c-net-projects/send-and-receive-sms-in-net-using-gprs-modem/

I downloaded the source code but the things are not quite clear.

thanks,
s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**ATCommands**](http://www.developershome.com/sms/smsIntro.asp) to communicate with GSM modem. This is very good [**codeproject article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com) for understanding  the procedure with demo.

Comment: Thank you so much ...link of Code project artical working successfully with my Nokia E63 and Windwos7 PC........thank you so much......

Answer (score 1):

You can use AT commands, or if you are on Windows 7 or 8, you can use the Mobile Broadband API.  There is yet another API if you are developing in Win 8 Metro.

Mobile Broadband API reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd323269(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a paper about using it with C# here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271(v=vs.85).aspx

The complete 3GPP AT command reference for GSM modems is TS 27.007, it is here: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm 
Be aware that most modems have manufacturer specific AT commands as well, some of which are public and some aren't.  But for simple procedures like sending/receiving SMSes, you probably won't need them.

The source code that you have will first identify programmatically which port the modem is connected on, and then it will send AT commands.  Or, it will identify the network adapter that represents the modem, and using the Windows id, will call Mobile Broadband API functions.  So look in the code for these procedures.  That's an interesting site, by the way - it was new to me.