# Receiving Packets of GPRS C#

Tags: c#

I have a GSM Device using GPRS Services, and sends the information (Packet), I want to have solution to receive those packets on my c# application.

I found out the socket programming is the way to do so, but I am asking if there is another way to sort-up the issue!

Comment: another solution is possible only if GSM device manufacturer provides .NET library in my opinion.

Comment: You might find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642057/basic-concept-for-sending-receiving-sms-from-c-sharp-application-using-gsm-modem/13642342#13642342  Your question is not specifically about SMS, but the same principles apply.

Comment: It depends exactly what sort of packets you are receiving (i.e. what layer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there sir if you have a static ip than the best solution would be socket programming and you dont need to have a gsm or gprs modem.